# Suma de dígitos de una fecha

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo pedir una fecha al usuario y que devuelva la suma de sus dígitos de esta manera?

```
12/09/1997 :
1+2+0+9+1+9+9+7 = 38  = 3 + 8 = 11 = 2
```

No entiendo cómo puedo separar los números como el 12 o 1997. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
static void option2() {

        int day, month, year;



    }

    private static int functionAdd(int number) {

        int result = 0;

        while (number > 0) {

            int d = number % 10;
            result += d;
            number /= 10;

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Tengo esto hecho, no sé cómo continuarlo creo que sería con un bucle `while` en `option2()`, pero no sé cómo crearlo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59546/discussion-on-question-by-pau-bacardit-agset-suma-de-digitos-de-una-fecha).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linq al rescate,en una sola linea:

```
string miCadena = "12/09/1997";
var suma = 
 1 +((miCadena.Where(x=>Char.IsDigit(x)).Select(x=>int.Parse(x.ToString())).Sum()) -1) % 9;
```

**EDIT**

Por si alguien no entiende la fórmula que utilizo, lo que OP trata de hallar se llama *Raiz digital* de un número. En [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitalRoot.html) podeis leer la explicación:

> La raiz digital dr(n) de un entero n puede ser calculada sin utilizar iteracion usando la formula simple de congruencia:

```
dr(n)   =   {n (mod 9) n ≢ 0 (mod 9) ; 
            {9 n≢0 (mod 9)  

        =   1+[n-1 (mod 9)].
```

**EDIT2**

De hecho, mi respuesta se puede simplificar aun mas, simplemente quitando los `/` del string de fecha original,omitiendo la necesidad de usar Linq:

```
string miCadena = "12/09/1997";
var suma = 1 + (int.Parse(miCadena.Replace("/", "")) - 1) % 9;
```

Comment: Asombroso  me quito el sombrero ante la reducción matemática. Te llevas mi +1 :) Quizá no sea ni necesaria la limpieza de la cadena si le dan los números en enteros, pero no queda muy claro en su pregunta :/

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, en realidad solo había que saber donde buscar ;)  Efectivamente no deja muy claro cual es su cadena de entrada pero creo que lo importante es el algoritmo

Comment: wow quieres ser mi maestro? XD esta muy bien me ha funcionado también (he probado todos los códigos) :)

Comment: No me veo yo de maestro no. Pero me alegro que te funcione @PauBacarditAgset :)

Answer (score 4):

Algo así te servirá:

```
String str="El lenguaje Java";
String subStr=str.substring(3, 11);
Se obtendrá el substring "lenguaje". Recuérdese, que las posiciones se empiezan a contar desde cero.
```

Con `str.substring(x,y)` parte lo que quieras de la variable. Por ejemplo en tu caso si quieres pillar el primer número sería `str.substring(0,1)`, el segundo `(1.2 )` y así sucesivamente. Pruébalo y dime si te funciona.

Comment: la cosa es que debo sumar todos los números de la fecha la cual indica el usuario, después sumar los dígitos del resultado y volver a sumar el segundo resultado

Comment: Pues haces un substring de todos los numeros. Haces un bucle y le dices que si lo que ha recogido es un numero, lo guarda en una variable, si no pasa de el. Entonces luego , cada vez que pase por el bucle, suma la variable mas el nuevo valor. Y ya esta.

Comment: asi me ha funcionado muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Se puede resolver el problema de manera recursiva o iterativa. Yo te proporciono una solución iterativa:

```
using System;

namespace pruebaSumaFecha
{
  class printHello
  {
    private static int sumaDigitos(string numero) {
      while (numero.Length > 1) {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (char c in numero) {
          int n = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c);
          if (n != -1) {
            total += n;
          }
        }
        numero = Convert.ToString(total);
      }
      return Int32.Parse(numero);
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      int day = 12, month = 9, year = 1997;
      string fecha = day.ToString("00") + "/" +
        month.ToString("00") + "/" +
        year.ToString("0000");
      Console.WriteLine("La suma de digitos de " + fecha +
        " es " + sumaDigitos(fecha));
    }
  }
}
```

En la función `sumaDigitos` calculo el valor numérico de cada carácter con [`Char.GetNumericValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/aa311572(v=vs.71)) (y lo convier el resultado de manera explícita de `double` a `int`), y si es un número el resultado no es -1 (valor devuelto en caso de fallo en la conversión) será un número correcto, por lo que lo sumaremos al total.

El proceso se repite componiendo de nuevo en `numero` el total obtenido en la iteración anterior y si tiene más de un carácter de longitud vuelvo a calcular la suma de sus caracteres.